# What is the difference if a shell script has ".sh" extension or not?

Tags: shell, unix, file-extension

I have two identical shell scripts: `A.sh` and `A`.

What is the difference?

Comment: If they are identical then there is no difference. Can you show your expected output?

Comment: Just a naming convention, nothing clever. Maybe some applications or file explorers can use the extension to show the file different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can even call it A.txt. Then give it execute permission and run it. If you give a .sh extension then others can easily identify that its a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Linux-based operating systems are concerned, the extension does not have any special meaning. You can have any name for your file. You can execute the script with the respective runtime.

For Bash: `sh sample.txt`

For Python: `python sample.txt`

For NodeJS: `node sample.txt`

For better maintainability of the code, you should give your filenames proper extensions like `.sh`, `.py`, `.js` and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,
Once your  /path/to/anyfunnyfilename script has execution privileges, if you want to run it without calling the interpreter, you can have the FIRST line of your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
code line 1
code line 2
...
code line n
```

it also apply for

```
#!/bin/perl
your perl code here
```

Another example:

```
#!/bin/python
your python code here

#!/bin/expect
your expect code here
```

And so on..

Hope this helps..